# Iterator error conversion from to non scalar type

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I must write a piece of code to remove any duplicates from a container std::list.
I have test different methods but one produces error that i don't understand. I report the wrong code:

```
  std::list<clock_t> cList;
  for(int i = 0;i< 5 ; ++i){
    for(int j = 0;j < 1000000 ;++j);
    cList.push_back(generatorClock()());
  }
  cList.sort();
  std::list<clock_t> cListUnique;
  std::list<clock_t>::iterator itEnd1 = **std::unique_copy(cList.begin(),cList.end(),std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<clock_t> >(cListUnique) );**
```

The error message is

```
"error: conversion from ‘std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<long int> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::list<long int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<long int>}’ requested"
```

Why do I obtain this error ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I assume the `**` are put there to indicate where the error is produced rather than being part of the actual source. Using `**` is a bad choice in C++ because it normally used to dereference an iterator or a pointer.

That said, `std::unique_copy()` returns an iterator indicating the end of the write sequence. You are writing to a `std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<clock_t> >` which doesn't really have any relation to a `std::list<clock_t>::iterator` even if the `std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<clock_t> >` is for a list of the same type. Also, you don't really need it: your `cListUnique` will contain the corresponding sequence of unique elements. It isn't like `std::unique()` where you need the end iterator to know where to cut off the sequence using, e.g., `erase()`.

Answer (score 0):

Return type of [unique_copy](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unique_copy.html):

```
OutputIterator unique_copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result);
```

is `OutputIterator`.

Try:

```
std::back_insert_iterator< std::list< int > > itEnd1 = std::unique_copy( cList.begin(), cList.end(), std::back_insert_iterator< std::list< int > >( cListUnique ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique_copy` must be returning `std::back_insert_iterator`

So instead of just iterator, you should try using back_insert_iterator:

```
std::list<clock_t>::back_insert_iterator itEnd1 = ...
```

the error is basically iAn that it's trying to assign back_insert_iterator to iterator.